# $0 \leq a \leq b \implies \sqrt{a}\leq \sqrt{b}$ in $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $a,b$ self-adjoint elements in a unital $C^*$-algebra. I'm trying to show that
$$0 \leq a \le b \implies \sqrt{a} \le \sqrt{b}$$ (these square roots are defined via functional calculus).

The hint I was given said to prove it first if $b$ is invertible, and I managed to do that.

Next, I attempted the case that $b$ is non-invertible. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. A standard argument using Gelfand's theorem shows that $b + \epsilon$ is invertible, and we have $a \le b + \epsilon$,so the former case applies and we get

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \sqrt{a} \leq \sqrt{b+ \epsilon}$$

Next, choose a sequence $\epsilon_n \searrow 0$. I want to show that

$$\sqrt{b+ \epsilon_n} \to \sqrt{b} \quad\quad (*)$$
Maybe this follows because $f_n \to f$ uniformly where $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x+\epsilon_n}$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ (via functional calculus)?

If I can deduce this, then from $$\forall n : \sqrt{a} \leq \sqrt{b+\epsilon_n}$$
we would obtain $\sqrt{a} \leq \sqrt{b}$ where implicitely was used that the positive elements are norm-closed.

So how can I justify $(*)$. Is the reason I said a good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that functional calculus is a $*$-homomorphism. Concretely, let $\Gamma:C(\sigma(b))\to C^*(b)$ be the Gelfand transform. Then
$$
\|f(b)-g(b)\|=\|\Gamma(f)-\Gamma(g)\|=\|\Gamma(f-g)\|\leq\|f-g\|.
$$

Comment: Ah yes, I believe it is even an isometry!

Comment: Does the above approach work though? Or is something wrong with it?

Comment: Yes. I answered to the part of your proof that contains the word "maybe".

Comment: Alright. Thanks. One more follow up question. Write $\Gamma_b$ for the functional calculus map w.r.t. the element $b$. In fact, I proved that if $c$ is invertible, then $\Gamma_a(x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) \leq \Gamma_c(x \mapsto \sqrt{x})$. Thus I applied this to get $\Gamma_a(x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) \leq \Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}(x \mapsto \sqrt{x})$. Would it be correct to say that $\Gamma_{b + \epsilon_n}(x) = \Gamma_{b}(x \mapsto \sqrt{x+\epsilon_n})$ because functional calculus respects the composition and then the above applies?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is if 'functional calculus respects composition' is implicitely used.

Comment: The elements $(b+\epsilon_n)^{1/2}$ are in $C^*(b)$ (if you consider it unital, which is the case here). So you are using a single $\Gamma$.

Comment: I don't quite understand, I proved $\Gamma_a( x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) \leq \Gamma_b( x \mapsto \sqrt{x})$ if $b$ is invertible. I apply this with the invertible elements $b+ \epsilon_n$, so I would obtain $\Gamma_a(x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) \leq \Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}(x \mapsto \sqrt{x})$. Then I still need to use that functional calculus respects composition to get it to $\Gamma_b$, right?

Comment: No. You have two functions, and you are evaluating both at $b$. There is no composition.

Comment: But how do I know that $\Gamma_b(x \mapsto \sqrt{x + \epsilon_n})$ is invertible then? This I don't know.

Comment: You have $$\sigma(f(b))=f(\sigma(b)).$$ If $f$ is not zero on $\sigma(b)$, then $f(b)$ is invertible.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I still don't understand. Let me try to rewrite because I don't see how that helps. I proved $a \leq b \implies \Gamma_a(x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) \leq \Gamma_b(x \mapsto \sqrt{x})$ IF $b$ is invertible. Now, assume the general case. Choose a sequence $0 < \epsilon_n \to 0$. Then I know that $b + \epsilon_n$ is invertible. Applying the result above $\Gamma_a(x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) \leq \Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}(x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) = \Gamma_{b}(x \mapsto \sqrt{x+\epsilon_n})$.

Comment: Letting $n \to \infty$ and using that positive elements are norm closed, we get $\Gamma_a(x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) \leq \Gamma_b(x \mapsto \sqrt{b})$. I really don't see why we don't need the maps $\Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}$

Comment: Neither do I. You wrote $\Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}$, 49 minutes ago.

Comment: I'm very confused by your response. How would you write this proof in terms of the maps $\Gamma_b$, avoiding the maps $\Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}$?

Comment: Call $g_n(t)=\sqrt{t+\varepsilon_n}$, $g(t)=\sqrt t$. Then $$\|g_n(b)-g(b)\|=\|\Gamma(g_n)-\Gamma(g)\|=\|g_n-g\|.$$

Comment: I agree with this. And how would you deduce that $\sqrt{a} \leq \Gamma(g_n) = \Gamma_b(g_n)$ from what I already proved?

Comment: I don't follow. You said you knew how to show that $a\leq b$ implies $a^{1/2}\leq (b+\varepsilon_n)^{1/2}$, and now you can take limit. What's the problem now?

Comment: No! I know how to show that $a \leq b \implies \Gamma_a(g) \leq \Gamma_b(g)$ when $b$ is invertible.

Comment: How can I conclude that $\Gamma_a(g) \leq \Gamma_b(g_n)$ from this? Strictly applying what I already know, I can see that $\Gamma_a(g) \leq \Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}(g)$. But you said that we don't need that functional calculus respects composition.

Comment: You have $a\leq b\leq b+\varepsilon_n$, so (as you said) you know how to show that $a^{1/2}\leq (b+\varepsilon)^{1/2}$. As you showed in your OP, you know how to show that the right-hand-side converges to $b^{1/2}$. At this stage I cannot possibly imagine what you are looking for.

Comment: I have $a \leq b \implies \Gamma_a(g) \leq \Gamma_b(g)$ when $b$ is invertible. Now, $b+ \epsilon_n$ is invertible, so I can deduce that $\Gamma_a(g) \leq \Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}(g)$. You seem to suggest that we can immediately say: $\Gamma_a(g) \leq \Gamma_b(g_n)$. Why is that so? To justify $\Gamma_{b+\epsilon_n}(g) = \Gamma_b(g_n)$ we need that functional calculus respects composition right?

Comment: I understand if you don't want to continue the discussion. Thanks for your time anyways!

Comment: I don't mind. And you are right, if you want to be precise you are using that $\Gamma$ is a homomorphism. It's just that it's usually not worth sweating about it.

Comment: Alright. I just wanted to write it out in extreme detail so next time I won't have to! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this from Arveson's book on Spectral Theorem. You can deduce what you want from his elegant approach.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but am I misunderstanding an answer? I want to show an inequality not show there is a square root.

Comment: @user745578 : You can deduce what you from the explicit form of the series, and the fact that the $c_n > 0$. This is an elementary approach. Knowing this approach is also useful for abstract $C^*$ algebra theory, where it allows you to build up the GNS construction. This is pre-Gelfand, and it is needed to build to GNS.