# Can the positive operator stay monotonicity？

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, positive-definite, self-adjoint-operators

If $A,B$ are two self-adjoint operators on Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, and assume $A\ge B \ge0$, which means that
$$
((A-B)f,f)\ge 0, \forall f \in D(A) \cap D(B),
$$
and
$$
\quad(Af_1,f_1) \ge0, (Bf_2,f_2) \ge0, \forall f_1 \in D(A), \;f_2 \in D(B),
$$
then can we conclude that
$$
A^s \ge B^s, \;\;\forall s>0? 
$$
where we can use spectral decomposition theorem to define $A^s, B^s$. The result is easy for  $\dim \mathscr{H}< \infty$, but when it comes to finite case, the continuous spectrum may occur, and then I am a little confused about how to compare them?

Comment: The result fails for $s>1$ but, at least when the operators are bounded, it is true for $s\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Thanks. But why the result fails for $s >1$? Are there some counterexample about it?

Comment: I have added an answer with a counter-example, let me know what you think:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example for $s=2$. We work in $H=\mathbb{C}^2$, so $B(H)\cong M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Simply take $a=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}7&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$. These are both positive matrices and note that $0\leq a\leq a+b$, where $a+b=\begin{pmatrix}8&1\\ 1&2\end{pmatrix}$. Note that

$$a^2=\begin{pmatrix}2&-2\\ -2&2\end{pmatrix} $$
$$(a+b)^2=\begin{pmatrix}65&10\\10&5\end{pmatrix} $$
However, $(a+b)^2-a^2=\begin{pmatrix}63&12\\12&3 \end{pmatrix}$ which is not positive (compute the eigenvalues and you can see it). Note that neither $a^2-(a+b)^2$ is positive! In particular, $(a+B)^2-a^2$ has two distinct eigenvalues, one positive and one negative.

Comment: Also, have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4126774/in-a-c-algebra-if-a-leq-b-then-a-alpha-leq-b-alpha-for-0-alpha/4127272#4127272

Comment: thank you for your answer, and I have seen the counterexample (I am very sorry for replying you so late). The reason why I raised this question is that I have seen a problem in Lezmann and Rupert paper which I give a link below. The question says that if  $A \ge B >0$ are two positive operator, then for any $\lambda>0$, we have $0 < (A+\lambda)^{-1} \le (B+\lambda)^{-1}$. And another reason is that  I want to compare $(-\Delta_l)^{s} \ge (-\Delta_{l'})^{s}$, $\forall s \in (0,N)$, where $-\Delta_{l}$ means the restriction of $-\Delta$ on to the spherically harmonic function space of degree l.

Comment: And we can see that $-\Delta_{l}= -\partial_r^2 - \frac{N-1}{r} \partial_r + \frac{l(l+N-2)}{r^2}$, and thus it of course means that $\Delta_{l} > \Delta_{l'}$ forall $l \ge l'$, and that day I wanted to check $(-\Delta_l)^s \ge (-\Delta_{l'})^s$. But these days through your answer I have realized that it may not hold for general index. But I still wonder can we have $(-\Delta_l+\lambda)^{-1} \le (-\Delta_{l'}+ \lambda)^{-1}$ for all $\lambda >0$?

Comment: the link is: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cpa.21591, and the related equation is (C.22) in this paper.